# Run-time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set with AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA and have referenced the Worksheet.AutoFilter property from microsoft documents, but I'm not sure how to set what is needed to stop this error from coming up. It is working fine but if something on the sheet is manually changed, this error will pop up. I'm trying to filter a table on this DT_Summary sheet by column B, all values greater than zero. I get an error on the 4th line with the autofilter.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Sheets("DT_Summary").Visible = True
   Sheets("DT_Summary").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
   Sheets("DT_Summary").Visible = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're filtering a table, use the relevant Listobject's Autofilter property, not the worksheet one.

Comment: What do you expect from `.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter`? It makes sense only after **already having a filter and you used `ShowAllData`**. Then, you should **never use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` if the code has not been designed in a way to not raise any error**.

Comment: Could you share what exactly *is working fine*? Where exactly is the table in the `DT_Summary` worksheet located? Why don't you share the screenshots of your worksheets? There are 2, aren't there? You mentioned column `B` and `>0` yet it's nowhere to be found in your code. Think about when this code should run; you usually want to run it when a change in one or a few columns, headers excluded, occurs.

Comment: It works fine until anything on DT_Summary sheet is changed manualy. I manually set the filter to have column b greater than 0. The filter is in B1, table is A1:B100. There are pivot tables starting at d:75 of 2 columns. Column A is a list of all downtime reasons we have, and column b of the table is a sum if that sums from the multiple pivots running down column D:E starting at row 75. There is a chart worksheet that has a chart from the table on DT_Summary (A1:B100), so everytime the slicer on the chart sheet is clicked, the DT_summary filters column b > 0 for only relevant downtime reasons.